# how to find the area of a wrapped cylinder

Tags: volume, area, solid-of-revolution

> Find the number of rolls required to wrap a $330$ ft long cylinder with an initial diameter of $1.75$ inches $5$ times. Each Roll is .$408$ inches thick, $24$ inches wide, and $20$ ft long. Each wrap must overlap $2$ inches.

I tried two methods, volume and surface area
my surface area method was find the SA of the cylinder at each wrap and divide it by the rectangular area of the roll then add them all together, then add the overlap after (kind of as an afterthought).

Area method is find the area of the new outer wrapped cylinder minus the area of the small internal cylinder

SA method i got $36.83$ with the overlap adding an additional $6.875$ rolls for a total of $~43$ rolls
A method i got $40.93$ with the overlap adding an additional $6.875$ rolls
for a total of $~48$ rolls

I need to be as accurate as humanly possible with this, and am struggling to understand why the difference between the two is so large. Conceptually, to me, they should both solve the problem.

Any ideas on how to get a very accurate answer here?

Comment: Because your material is thick compared to the diameter you are winding it around, you need to specify how it gets laid down.  The first wrap is $1.75$ inside diameter and $2.566$ outside diameter.  Where do you measure the length-the inside, the outside, or in the middle?  Can you wrap it that tightly?  Does the inner surface compress, the outer surface stretch, or some of each?

Comment: You also have to think about  the ramp as you approach the overlap.  You are coming around the cylinder and see a vertical step $0.408$ high.  How does the material cross the step?  It is probably most natural to leave the cylinder on a tangent that touches the top of the step, make a crease at the top of the step, and start winding again.  For high accuracy you need to specify this.

Comment: @RossMilikan for the sake of the problem, lets say we are measuring it as if it is wrapped perfectly tight, but each layer ads EXACTLY .408 to the radius this the first outside diameter is 1.75 before wrap, and after the wrap 2.566 then 3.382 etc. As for the overlap, once you get to the overlap, you continue with more, not actually overlapping the material, its almost like adding 10 inches to the whole wrap.

Comment: That is a fine answer to how we do the wrap, but you still haven't answered whether we consider the length of one wrap the inside, the middle, or the outside of the wrap.  Once we have that we can do the calculation.

Comment: I was reacting to your statement that you needed the calculation to be as perfect as humanly possible.  If we specify the wrapping properly, it is possible to do the calculation perfectly until we substitute in a value for $\pi$, but we need to define the problem. I have used one assumption, which I think is reasonable, in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume we measure the length of a wrap at the center of the thinckness.  This has the appealing feature that the volume of wrapping material stays constant as we wrap.  The radius of the first wrap is then $(1.75+.408)/2=1.079$ and the radii increase by $0.408$ each time.  Your five wraps then have radii of $1.079, 1.487, 1.895, 2.303,$ and $2.711$.  The total length is $2\pi (1.079+ 1.487+ 1.895+ 2.303+2.711)+10=18.95\pi+10$ were the $+10$ comes from the overlaps.  The area to cover is then $330\cdot 12 \cdot (18.95 \pi +10)$ and if we can use rolls perfecly we need $\frac {330\cdot 12 \cdot (18.95 \pi +10)}{24\cdot 240}$ rolls.  So far, this is perfect if your dimensions are.  It comes out about $47.804062$ rolls

Comment: This is actually a little higher than I got 47.6 but close enough to feel comfortable thank you so much!